# Here Is my error for the my javascript code

Tags: javascript

I attempt one javascript assignment and there is four task which I mentioned in my code. but somehow I am getting problem in my 2nd task.where I have to make function but I didn't get idea what is going wrong.

```
> Passed Test 1: successfully logged consoleStyler() variables
> Failed Test 2: Not logging celebrateStyler() variables
> Failed Test 3: Not calling consoleStyler() and celebrateStyler()
> Passed Test 4: successfully called styleAndCelebrate()
```

Here is my code.
// Task 1: Build a function-based console log message generator

```
function consoleStyler(color,background,fontSize,txt) {

    var message = "%c" + txt;
    var style = `color: ${color};`
    style += `background: ${background};`
    style += `font-size: ${fontSize};`
    
    console.log(message,style)
    
}
```

// Task 2: Build another console log message generator

```
function celebrateStyler(reason) {
    var fontStyle = "color: tomato; font-size: 50px";
    if(reason == "birthday")
    {
        console.log("%cHappy Birthday", fontStyle);
    }else if(reason == "champions")
    {
        console.log("%cCongrats on the title!", fontStyle);
    } else {
        console.log(message, style);
    }
}
```

// Task 3: Run both the consoleStyler and the celebrateStyler functions

```
consoleStyler('#1d5c63', '#ede6db', '40px', 'Congrats!')
celebrateStyler('birthday')
```

// Task 4: Insert a congratulatory and custom message

```
function styleAndCelebrate(color, background, fontSize, txt,reason) {
    
   consoleStyler(color, background, fontSize, txt);
    celebrateStyler(reason);
}
```

// Call styleAndCelebrate

```
styleAndCelebrate('ef7c8e','fae8e0','30px','You made it!','champions')
```

Comment: You failed 2/4 tests, but we don't really know what these tests are testing _for_. If it's just logging _something_ it should work, but clearly it wouldn't or your tests would be fine...